# Is the subgroup $1+\langle x,y\rangle\subset\mathbb{Z}_p[[x,y]]^\times$ generated as a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module by $1+x,1+y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-groups

Consider the power series ring in 2 variables with coefficients in the $p$-adic integers:
$$\mathbb{Z}_p[[x,y]]$$
It's group of units consists of precisely the power series with constant coefficient a unit.

There is an embedding $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p[[x,y]]^\times$ given by sending $(a,b)\mapsto (1+x)^a(1+y)^b$.

Is this map surjective onto the subgroup $1+\langle x,y\rangle$ of power series with constant coefficient equal to 1?

Comment: $1 + x$ and $1 + y$ are units. Also, can you explain what you mean by $1 + \langle x, y \rangle$ because to me that notation means a coset of an ideal, not an ideal.

Comment: Take $u=1+(x-y)\in1+\langle x,y\rangle$. This element satisfies $(u-1)_{x=y}=0$. On the other hand, for an element $v$ on the image of that embedding $(v-1)|_{x=y}=(1+x)^{a+b}-1=(a+b)x+\text{terms of higher order}$ has order $1$, and therefore it is not zero unless $a=-b$. For $a=-b$ we have $v-1=0$ but $u-1=x-y$, which is non-zero.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Ah sorry I meant to refer to the subgroup of power series with constant term equal to 1

Comment: @Marja I'm not sure what your conclusion is...

Comment: That $1+x-y$ is not in the image of the embedding.

Comment: @Marja If $a = -b$, then $v-1 = (1+x)^a(1+y)^{-a}$, which is only zero modulo $x-y$, and is not zero in the original ring. Similarly, $u-1 = x-y$, which is also only zero modulo $x-y$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. We can look at the continuous surjection:
$$\mathbb{Z}_p[[x,y]]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/\Phi_p(x+1) = \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$$
sending $x\mapsto x$ and $y\mapsto 0$, where $\Phi_p(T) = T^{p-1} + T^{p-2} + \cdots + T + 1$ is the $p$th cyclotomic polynomial, so $\zeta_p$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity (in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$), and $1+x\mapsto\zeta_p$.

Under this map, the image of $x$ is $\zeta_p-1$, which is a uniformizer for the discrete valuation ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p]$, so the image of $1+\langle x,y\rangle$ is the coset $1+\langle\zeta_p-1\rangle$, which is a coset of a finite index ideal, hence infinite.

On the other hand, the image of the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module generated by $1+x$ is just the finite group generated by $\zeta_p$, hence is a proper subgroup of $1+\langle\zeta_p-1\rangle$ of infinite index.